# Error converting a list of variables to INT in Robot Framework

Tags: python, variables, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

hello!

Is it possible in Robot Framework to create a list and the variables to be of type INT or NUMBER?

I tried in the form, but without success...

**Attempt 1**

```
${TEST_1}    Create List    01    61
${TEST_1}    Convert To Integer    ${TEST_1}
Set Suite Variable    ${TEST_1}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
@{TEST_2}    Replace Variables    0    9
@{TEST_2}    Convert To Integer    @{TEST_2}
Set Suite Variable    ${TEST_2}
```

**Errors already displayed on attempts:**

> 'None' cannot be converted to an integer: TypeError: int() argument
> must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

> '01' cannot be converted to an integer: ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36, or 0

can anybody help me?

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The robot framework user guide describes [number variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#number-variables) which are a way to define integers and floating point numbers.

The syntax is to simply wrap the number in `${}`. For example, `${1}` represents the integer `, and` ${3.14}`represents the floating point number`3.14`. You can also define values with octal, hex, binary, and scientific notation.

Using  your code as an example, you can create a list of integers like this:

```
${TEST_1}    Create List    ${1}    ${61}
```

Comment: Very thanks!! Resolved!

Comment: Bryan Oakley, could you help me in link below? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019122/error-when-calling-url-using-soaplibrary-library