# Error when calling URL using SoapLibrary library

Tags: xml, soap, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm automating tests with Robot Framework using SoapLibrary, Collections, OperatingSystem, XML and Process Libraries.

When I send my XML on a Soap endpoint I get the following error:

> XMLSyntaxError: Invalid XML content received (Opening and ending tag
> mismatch: META line 1 and head, line 22, column 8)

I realized that the problem is not the XML sent, but the URL. But the URL is the same as the one sent via Soap (and via Soap it goes successfully).

How do I send an XML to my address?

```
*** Variables ***
    ${URL}    http://localhost:81/WS/DLL/JDSPB_WS_IntegraLegado.dll/soap/IJDSPBCAB
                
*** Test Cases ***

Test Call Soap
    
    Create Soap Client    ${URL}

    ${response}    Call SOAP Method With XML    ${CURDIR}/FILETEST.xml
```

If I replace "soap" in the URL with "wsdl", it works! But the call is not made. Only documentation is returned, just like SOAP.

Can you help me?

Comment: no one can help me?

Comment: Could you help me?!